# Doxygen [C] : hiding file names

Tags: c, doxygen

Im using Doxygen to document a static C library. The include directory of that library contains several header files but in practice the developer only needs to include a single file (ie #include ) because it already includes the remaining ones.

However when the documentation is generated HTML navigation is accomplished through the header files name which have a link. How can I avoid that? I want something like Qt documentation, where the file names are hiden, you focus only on the classes name.
Since C doesnt have classes, I think should use some kind of grouping for functions, enums, etc I want to document.

Any suggestion?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group symbols using @defgroup and @ingroup, see http://www.doxygen.org/manual/grouping.html for more info.